# R- Bind two different dataframes with different lenght by adding NA or boolean criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, rbind

I have the following 2 databases(only showing head and tail)

**DF 1**

```
dput(head(df1))
structure(list(id = c(43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48), seed = 
c(919028655, 
119103778, 110460177, 724234636, 661955607, 1505343599)), 
row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")


dput(tail(df1))
structure(list(id = c(183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188), seed = 
c(618503388, 
1892186421, 1623243403, 1851570303, 26744271, 152317517)), 
row.names = 140:145, class = "data.frame")
```

this one has a length of 145 rows and each participant as a unique ID number.

**DF 2**

This one is the result of a variable that had to be sent to external judges. Once they returned the data, they gave me a CSV with only 130 rows (making cbind impossible and doubts about scores matchig participants unique ID)

```
dput(head(df2))
structure(list(Response.ID = 43:48, DTT_SCORE.fluency = c(NA, 
NA, 3L, 4L, 14L, NA), 
DTT_SCORE.fluencyAll = c(NA, 
NA, 2L, 4L, 9L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
"data.frame")

dput(tail(df2))
structure(list(Response.ID = 168:173, DTT_SCORE.fluency = 
c(NA, 
NA, NA, 6L, 5L, 5L), 
DTT_SCORE.fluencyAll = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 8L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = 125:130, class = 
"data.frame")
```

**Question 1**

Just by eye the id row seems to match with the original one, it just stops at the 130th item. Would there be a way to force the two data frames to bind by forcing non existing rows to appear as NA (turning the 130 long df into a 145 long df with rows from 130 to 145 as empty or NA)

**Question 2**

As every respondent has a unique ID would it be a way to write a dataframe that displays the values only if id on df1 matches id on df2, for example,

if df1$id == df2$id display (df2$DTT SCORE.fluency)*1 , else
if df1$id != df2$id display (df2$DTT SCORE.fluency)*0

Comment: This looks more of an `R` tag question, removing pandas tag

Comment: Are you looking for `merge(df1, df2, by.x="id", by.y="Response.ID")`?

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, you actually needs a join operation. As you sad, if the id's in both tabels, in each row, matched, you could use `cbind()`. But since, you cannot assure that anymore, is best to use a join to make this matching for you. The `base` R have the `merge()` function for that. Since the name of column of ids in your DF2 are different, I just rename it, the same way as this column appears in the DF1.

```
colnames(df2)[1] <- "id"
merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

**Resulting this:**

```
    id       seed DTT_SCORE.fluency DTT_SCORE.fluencyAll
1   43  919028655                NA                   NA
2   44  119103778                NA                   NA
3   45  110460177                 3                    2
4   46  724234636                 4                    4
5   47  661955607                14                    9
6   48 1505343599                NA                   NA
7  183  618503388                NA                   NA
8  184 1892186421                NA                   NA
9  185 1623243403                NA                   NA
10 186 1851570303                NA                   NA
11 187   26744271                NA                   NA
12 188  152317517                NA                   NA
```

For creating a table displaying the ids of DF1 that appears in DF2, you can use the following code:

```
ids <- data.frame(
  ids = unique(df1$id)
)

ids$test <- ids$ids %in% unique(df2$id)
```

**Resulting this:**

```
   ids  test
1   43  TRUE
2   44  TRUE
3   45  TRUE
4   46  TRUE
5   47  TRUE
6   48  TRUE
7  183 FALSE
8  184 FALSE
9  185 FALSE
10 186 FALSE
11 187 FALSE
12 188 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Both questions can be solved using the `dplyr` `*_join()` functions. In base R, `merge()` has similar functionality.

To combine all the rows from each dataframe, you can use `full_join()`. By default, the `*_join` functions match by any columns with the same name, but since your ID columns are named differently I specify it manually:

```
library(dpylr)

full_join(df1, df2, by = c("id" = "Response.ID"))
```

Any IDs which only appear in one table will have `NA` in the other columns.

If you want to only keep IDs that appear in both dataframes, you can replace `full_join` with `inner_join` instead. If you want to keep all the rows from `df1`, and only the matching rows for `df2` use `left_join` (or `right_join` for the opposite way round).